# A basic JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

Hello I need help with this basic bit of JavaScript. It just doesn't work for me; I have spent the last few hours pulling my hair out over it.

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function(){
  if (!document.getElementById) return false;
  var popupLink = document.getElementById("popup");
  popupLink.onclick = function() 
  {
    winOpen(this.getAttribute("href"));
    return false;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="popup.html" id="popup" title="select this link to open a popup in a new window">Open Popup Window</a>
```

I know it's probably something really silly i have missed, and any help from you guys would be a great welcome. The idea is to have no JavaScript in the HTML code other than the script link.

Comment: Did you define `winOpen` anywhere? Also, we don't do urgent, we are all volunteers.

Comment: [**`window.open`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)?

Comment: `if (!document.getElementById)` - because we still need to be sure, right.

Comment: Check the options in your browser, make sure that opening windows via script is allowed. Some browsers are not allowed by default, most can be set that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var popupLink = document.getElementById("popup");
  popupLink.onclick = function() 
  {
    winOpen(this.getAttribute("href"));
    return false;
  }
}

function winOpen(url)
{
  window.open(url);
}
```

### HTML:

```
<a href="popup.html" id="popup" title="select this link to open a popup in a new window">Open Popup Window</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was what i needed, just missed the function bit at the bottom :/ ok thats enough pulling hair out for one day going to buy a wig and have a red bull, thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

html for your code:

```
<a id="popup" href="http://jsfiddle.net/">click me</a>​
```

Test example, is it work?
http://jsfiddle.net/F2YCD/2/

Comment: hello, i tried that code didn't work i need it to open in a new window via javascript i can do it by defining it in the html code however the idea is not to do it that way and define it in the javascript, 1st time doing it this way and sadly its not going well

Comment: do you need target="_blank" attribute?

<a id="popup" href="http://jsfiddle.net/" target="_blank">click me</a>​

Comment: no had to do it with javascript one of the other replies was what i needed, thanks for the help thought was much appreciated.

Comment: There is javascript example. Just goto this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/F2YCD/2/)